# Simple Mysql select row inconsistencies. I can't figure out why. Is it me or mysql?

Tags: mysql, grails

My Grails application makes a very simple call to find the details of the logged in user. It is basically this:

```
select id, username, password, firstname, lastname from Person where id=3;
```

Somes time get a result, and sometimes not. I've been analyzing the sql being sent, and it doesn't make sense to me. One request will find the Person, and a subsequent request will not. The logs below track the thread id, session id, and logged in user. I know it is not great asking folks to look at my sql query logs, but I hope I have managed to make it clear in the below what I am seeing.

```
2701 [INFO] 2012-12-03 02:19:02,136 audit [T-82] [23212190391C07976A2CC568F06A780A] [cb18b110954f4476b80c2@stratus5.com] 3. 
Connection.prepareStatement(select person0_.id as id4_0_, person0_.version as version4_0_, 
person0_.account_expired as account3_4_0_, person0_.account_locked as account4_4_0_, 
person0_.created_date as created5_4_0_, person0_.email_hash as email6_4_0_, person0_.enabled as enabled4_0_, person0_.first_name as first8_4_0_, 
person0_.last_name as last9_4_0_, person0_.`password` as password10_4_0_, person0_.password_expired as password11_4_0_, person0_.tmp_password as tmp12_4_0_, 
person0_.username as username4_0_ from person person0_ where person0_.id=?)     

2702 [INFO] 2012-12-03 02:19:02,137 audit [T-82] [23212190391C07976A2CC568F06A780A] 
[cb18b110954f4476b80c2@stratus5.com] 3. PreparedStatement.setLong(1, 1160)

2749 [DEBUG] 2012-12-03 02:19:02,278 SignUpApiController [T-82]
[23212190391C07976A2CC568F06A780A] [cb18b110954f4476b80c2@stratus5.com] 
user: com.stratus5.auth.Person : 1160

280 [INFO] 2012-12-03 02:15:32,143 audit [T-160] [23212190391C07976A2CC568F06A780A] [cb18b110954f4476b80c2@stratus5.com] 5. Connection.prepareStatement(select person0_.id as id4_0_, person0_.version as version4_0_, 
 person0_.account_expired as account3_4_0_, 
 person0_.account_locked as account4_4_0_, 
 person0_.created_date as created5_4_0_, person0_.email_hash as email6_4_0_, 
 person0_.enabled as enabled4_0_, person0_.first_name as first8_4_0_, 
 person0_.last_name as last9_4_0_, person0_.`password` as password10_4_0_, 
 person0_.password_expired as password11_4_0_, person0_.tmp_password as tmp12_4_0_, 
 person0_.username as username4_0_ from person person0_ 
 where person0_.id=?) 

281 [INFO] 2012-12-03 02:15:32,143 audit [T-160] [23212190391C07976A2CC568F06A780A] 
[cb18b110954f4476b80c2@stratus5.com] 5. PreparedStatement.setLong(1, 1160) 

313 [DEBUG] 2012-12-03 02:15:32,939 SignUpApiController [T-160] 
[23212190391C07976A2CC568F06A780A] [cb18b110954f4476b80c2@stratus5.com] 
Current user: null
```

Here is some code extracts incase they help:

```
def principalId = new Long(springSecurityService.getPrincipal().id)
def p = Person.get(principalId)
log.debug "Current user: $p"
```

I had been just using the springSecurityService.currentUser and was seeing the same errors. I changed just to deliberately calling Person.get based on the hypothesis the problem could have been in the springSecurityService, but that now looks highly unlikely.

Comment: The select and the logs look simple enough. Since there's no obvious error, it might be somewhere else in your groovy code.

Comment: For the first thread, in the logs, I can see mysql returns expected data, and in the second it does not. I'm with you in thinking it must be something I'm doing, but everything is so simple, I can't see what it could be.

Comment: Can you add the code that generates the query and the code that prints 'Current user'?

Comment: I have added as you have asked. I'm afraid I don't think it will be of much use. But thanks for looking anyway @SérgioMichels

Comment: The id you are passing is probaly an object and not primitive type. Long == Long is not the same as long == long. Try to hardcode the id like def p = Person.get(1160). If its help, then make shure that your service delivers objects for witch the equals() method is true.

Comment: The code and logs look good. Do you have a single database running or some kind of cluster? Have you tried to eliminate groovy/grails as source of failure by sending the request directly through another tool like mySQL Workbench?

Comment: It's just a single database. I think it is 5.1 with InnoDB. I've considered upgrading to 5.5 just to see, but never got around to it. The thing about testing with mySQL workbench is that eventually the code above works - it's just something weird at signup time / user creation time - maybe a bug in InnoDb to do with transactions and multiviews. Of course more likely to be in my code than Mysqls, but I really investigated until there were no leads left.

Comment: In the end, my solution was to loop until the code above found a result.